# dict.get returning None when trying to initialize with empty list and appending value to it

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an empty dict and I want to check if key is present on not, if key is not present create a list append a value to it. If it's already present then append new value to it. But I am seeing it returning `None`

```
# Code
policy_models = {}
res = ['1', '1', '2', '3', 'x']
for idx, r in enumerate(res):
    p = policy_models.get(r, []).append(r)
    print(idx, r,p)
```

```
# Output
0 1 None # See how we have None in output even though key is not present whereas it should be [1, 1]
1 1 None
2 2 None
3 3 None
4 x None
```

The above code is modified and it's creates a list

```
policy_models = {}
res = ['1', '1', '2', '3', 'x']
for idx, r in enumerate(res):
    p = policy_models.get(r, [])#.append(r)
    print(idx, r,p)
```

In above code I have commented `append(r)` and got a list as expected.

```
# output
0 1 []
1 1 []
2 2 []
3 3 []
4 x []
```

How can I create a list and insert the value at the same time while extracting it from dict ? And why this behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Claudio I have updated the question, so people don't get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `setdefault`:

```
policy_models.setdefault(r, []).append(...)
```

Comment: Can you check at your end if this works as expected. I have added this as part of my example as it didn't work for me.

Comment: Just print `policy_models` after the loop. You don't need this `p` variable.

Answer (score 0):

And here an answer to the *And why this behavior?* part of the question. Using what is called 'print debugging' reveals how it comes that the list `p` remains empty:

```
policy_models = {}
res = ['1', '1', '2', '3', 'x']
for i, r in enumerate(res):
    if i > 0:
        print('BEFORE   p=policy_models.get(r,[]): ' f'{r=} {p=} {policy_models=}')
    else:
        print('BEFORE   p=policy_models.get(r,[]): ' f'{r=} (no p yet) {policy_models=}')

    p = policy_models.get(r, [])

    print(    '   AFTER p=policy_models.get(r,[]): ' f'{r=} {p=} {policy_models=}')
    print()
```

outputs:

````
BEFORE   p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='1' (no p yet) policy_models={}
   AFTER p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='1' p=[] policy_models={}

BEFORE   p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='1' p=[] policy_models={}
   AFTER p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='1' p=[] policy_models={}

BEFORE   p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='2' p=[] policy_models={}
   AFTER p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='2' p=[] policy_models={}

BEFORE   p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='3' p=[] policy_models={}
   AFTER p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='3' p=[] policy_models={}

BEFORE   p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='x' p=[] policy_models={}
   AFTER p=policy_models.get(r,[]): r='x' p=[] policy_models={}```
````

As you can see from the above, the list `p` remains empty because the `policy_models` dictionary, contrary to your expectations, remains empty returning always an empty list on `get`. And it remains empty because you don't assign a value to it. To assign a value to it you need to use `setdefault` instead of `get`. And as suggested in the accepted answer to populate the list being a value in the `policy_models` dictionary you need to use `.append(...)`.

Comment: This still doesn't assign anything into `policy_models`.

Comment: @AKX: see updated answer fixing the reason for your remark.

Comment: You're still only ever reading from `policy_models`. See the accepted answer (using `.setdefault`, not `.get`.)

Comment: And you are still not realizing that my answer explains *Why this behavior?* part of the question and ends with pointing to the accepted answer for a solution.